# Custom function + groupby Pandas with different conditions on grouped by variables

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to generate some weights using groupby on a data that originally looks like this :

```
V1   V2   MONTH  CHOICES  PRIORITY
X    T1   M1     C1       1
X    T1   M1     C2       0
X    T1   M1     C3       0
X    T2   M1     C1       1
X    T2   M1     C5       0
X    T2   M1     C6       0
X    T2   M1     C2       1
X    T1   M2     C1       1
X    T1   M2     C2       0
X    T1   M2     C3       0
X    T2   M2     C1       0
X    T2   M2     C5       1
X    T2   M2     C6       0
X    T2   M2     C2       1
```

Basically, when the MONTH is different than M1, I want to have flagged choices with weights equal to double any non flagged choice.
Example : if you have (C1, C2, C3) and C1 is the only one flagged, weights would be : 0.5 / 0.25 / 0.25.

On the same time, for the first month, I want the weights to be solely focused on flagged choices. Previous example would become (1/0/0).

Precision about the data :
For a given tuple (V1,V2,MONTH), we can have at most two choices flagged as priorities (no priority at all is a possibility).

Here's what I've tried :

```
def weights_preferences(data):
     if (data.MONTH.values != 'M1'):
         data['WEIGHTS'] = 1/(len(data)+data[data.PRIORITY==1].shape[0])
         data['WEIGHTS'] = data.apply(lambda x : 2*x.WEIGHTS if x.PRIORITY==1 else x.WEIGHTS, axis=1)
     elif data.MONTH.values == 'M1' & data[data.PRIORITY==1].shape[0]==0 :
         data['WEIGHTS'] = 1/(len(data))
     else :
         if data[data.PREFERENCE==1].shape[0]==1 :
             data['WEIGHTS'] = [1 if x[1].PRIORITY==1 else 0 for x in data.iterrows()]
         else :
             data['WEIGHTS'] = [0.5 if x[1].PRIORITY==1 else 0 for x in data.iterrows()]
     return data

tmp = tmp.groupby(['V1','V2','MONTH']).apply(weights_preferences)
```

The problem is that since I groupby 'MONTH', it seems that the value no longer appears in data on which 'weights_preferences' is applied.

P.S : Output would look like this

```
V1   V2   MONTH  CHOICES  PRIORITY  WEIGHTS
X    T1   M1     C1       1         1
X    T1   M1     C2       0         0
X    T1   M1     C3       0         0
X    T2   M1     C1       1         0.5
X    T2   M1     C5       0         0
X    T2   M1     C6       0         0
X    T2   M1     C2       1         0.5
X    T1   M2     C1       1         0.5
X    T1   M2     C2       0         0.25
X    T1   M2     C3       0         0.25
X    T2   M2     C1       0         0.16
X    T2   M2     C5       1         0.33
X    T2   M2     C6       0         0.16
X    T2   M2     C2       1         0.33
```

Any suggestions are very welcomed !

Thanks.

Comment: What should the final results look like?

Comment: Your sample data is all `M1` we cannot test your fist condition `if (data.MONTH.values != 'M1'):`

Comment: @piRSquared I added that to original post